# Преобразование массива в два других

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть объект, возвращенный через ajax:

```
{1: [37, 142], 4:[454, 471]}
```

Как на JS или jQuery его преобразовать в два массива вида:

```
[1, 4]
[37, 142, 454, 471]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

видимо как-то так

```js
const data = {1: [37, 142], 4:[454, 471]}

let keys = Object.keys(data).map(v => +v);
console.log(keys);

let values = Object.values(data).reduce((acc,v) => acc.concat(v), []);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 6):

Для получения массивов можно использовать следующий код:

```js
let data = {
  1: [37, 142],
  4: [454, 471]
};
let keys = Object.keys(data);
let values = [];
Object.values(data).forEach(e => values = values.concat(e))
console.log(keys, values);
```

Поскольку вам надо получать два отдельных массив, то по предложенной структуре явно видно, что первый массив - массив ключей, а второй объединенный массив значений. Поскольку значения исходного `json` являются массивами, то вам необходимо объединить их с помощью метода [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).